# SVN: Ignore but NOT delete a folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a junk folder, where my application puts temporary files. I don't want to commit them (surely), but the folder must exists or application will crash.

If I use standard TortoiseSVN ignore feature, it will add "svn:ignore junk_folder" property to parent folder, but it will also delete "junk_folder" which cannot happen.

If I revert only delete operation (did by TortoiseSVN) but leave adding "svn:ignore" property, this solution will fail. TortoiseSVN will report files inside "junk_folder" as non-versioned, which I want to avoid.

Is there any solution that would allow me to completely ignore particular folder in SVN (so no matter, what will be put in it, won't be reported as unversioned and won't be auto commited as well) without deleting it?

**EDIT**: *I forgot to add that I'm talking about already versioned folder. It seems that, if you ignore (svn:ignore or proper option in TortoiseSVN) a folder that wasn't yet versioned (before first commit) then everything is OK. But, if you do this on the folder that already was in repository, TortoiseSVN marks it as deleted and deletes it from both repository (but not from Local Working Copy) upon next commit.*

Comment: Could you not simply add the folder and none of its contents, so checking out will produce an empty folder?

Comment: @Wug - I think because his app will create files there, so he doesn't want SVN constantly telling him there are unversioned files in that directory.

Comment: Exactly. I don't want any reports about contents or changes in this folder, especially because there are thousands of files and folders inside that junk folder, and my commit dialog gets overloaded with such entries.

Comment: So, add the folder, and set `svn:ignore *` on the `junk_folder`, ignoring the contents of that folder rather then the folder itself?

Comment: I have a few svn projects with things like configuration directories and logging directories which must be present and are themselves versioned, but have no versioned contents.  SVN doesnt bother me about them.  Maybe I'm just using it wrong :)

Comment: @trejder, perhaps if you told us what version of TortoiseSVN you are using? Is it a really old version? Because `ignore` should not be doing any deletion.

Comment: @all: Thank you all for contribution. I'm using newest stable version available. The problem has been solved, as I wrote in EDIT to question and in some comments here. If you add any _unversioned_ folder to ingore list then it is not deleted. But if you do the same with folder already versioned, TortoiseSVN will delete it from repostory (but not from LWC) upon next commit. And from that moment, anyone who'll do update or clean full checkout from the repository will get it **without** that junk_folder. Which means a crash of an application in my case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you can just add an svn:ignore for "*" within that folder, instead of on "junk_folder" itself (in other words, ignore "junk_folder/*").

I don't know if TortoiseSVN has a button for that, but from the command line you can do it with the command:

> svn propset svn:ignore "*" junk_folder

(at least I think that is the right syntax, off the top of my head. if someone thinks that is wrong, please correct me)

Comment: I should note that this method still has an empty "junk_folder" checked in to SVN, so when you do a clean checkout, you will get an empty "junk_folder", but SVN won't tell you about any unversioned files that get created in that folder later. I think that is what you were asking for...

Comment: And that is EXACTLY what I need! :] I need to have "junk_folder" (empty) checked out upon each checkout to a new folder. And I need anything what is inside it, to be ignored. Your solution is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I use this for things like compiler intermediate output folders, and it has never deleted anything.

To re-test this, I found an *unversioned* directory in one of my working copies. I right clicked on the directory, and navigated to the "Add to ignore list" option. It expanded to the directory name. I selected the directory name and received a pop up message noting that it had been added to the ignore list. Checking the working copy status, the parent folder had a property only modification. No files were marked for deletion.

[Ignoring Files And Directories](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html)

[image]

**As a side note**, you can also hide unversioned files when using "Check for Modifications" and Commit dialogs with a checkbox near the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: That is very strange what you wrote! Whenever I use this option, it immediately marks such folder as deleted and actually deletes it upon next commit. Which leads an application to a crash. This is tested about hundred of times, so I can't belive that you use this option on a folder (not a file!) and don't get this folder deleted upon next commit.

Comment: in the screenshot, crashmstr would have right-clicked on a file within the folder (named Copy.bak in this case), not on the folder itself.

Comment: The screen is from the TorsoiseSVN documentation. The example screen is a file, but you can do the same for a directory, you would just see the folder name instead of the file name / extension options.

Comment: I just tried this (again) on a non-versioned folder. The status is now that the parent folder is "modified (property change only)" pending a commit. No deletes.

Comment: Correct, however the OP stated that ignoring the folder will also cause it to be deleted: *"If I use standard TortoiseSVN ignore feature, it will add "svn:ignore junk_folder" property to parent folder, but it will also delete "junk_folder" which cannot happen."*

Comment: see my comment from just a bit ago, I tried this again (which I have done before), and **no files were deleted**. I don't see how an ignore would do a delete anyway.

Comment: Ah good point crashmstr; if the folder was already versioned, then SVN will do the delete, to get the now-ignored folder out of SVN. If the folder was never versioned, then it doesn't bother with the delete.

Comment: @crashmstr: rally25rs is right (and solved the problem below). I forgot to mention that we're all talking about already versioned folder.If you add any _unversioned_ folder to ingore list then you're right -- it is not deleted. But if you do the same with folder already versioned, TortoiseSVN will delete it from repostory (but not from LWC) upon next commit. And from that moment, anyone who'll do update or clean full checkout from the repository will get it **without** that junk_folder. Which means a crash of an application in my case.So for folders already versioned

Comment: @crashmstr: So for folders already versioned the only option is to use "svn:ignore *" to ignore contents of such folder.

Comment: Your app should probably create the folder instead of crashing, by the way. *YES*, if the folder is versioned, then the only way to ignore is to *unversion* first. That is stated in the documentation that I linked to above.

Comment: Since this is a web application, so I think, we cannot freely talk about auto creation of necessary folders. Due to permissions. Beside, this is how the framework, I used, works, so any discussion on this matter have to be addressed to framework authors, not me.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Eclipse Subversive and Tortoise SVN.

My approach to this problem is to use the properties dialog from Tortoise (but I think Eclipse has the same feature)

If you right click on a folder in your working copy, e.g 'tmp' or 'cache' etc you can simply add the 'svn:ignore' property and put a wild card in there. You need to use the advanced button to add it because its not the the quick list of properties to add.

I am developing websites mostly on Joomla, and regularly installers or other components leave files in places that I don't want in the repo. And as mentioned 'svn:ignore'ing these folders using the 'right click ignore' method means these folder are completely excluded from the repo which is not what you want - you want the contents of those folders excluded, or sometimes just files with a certain extension.

after getting much advice from stackoverflow I signed up today to just to answer this question so hope it helps someone - I tried to attach screen shot but not enough rep :(

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "*If I use standard TortoiseSVN ignore feature, it will add `svn:ignore junk_folder` property to parent folder, but it will also delete `junk_folder`...*"?

Subversion does not delete a folder you ask it to ignore. In fact, that's the whole purpose of `svn:ignore`: To allow you to have a folder that's not in the repository without Subversion whining about it.

How is this `junk_folder` created? Is it by a script you use, or do you do it manually? Exactly when does it get deleted? Do you mean when you do a new checkout, `junk_folder` isn't there, or that TortoiseSVN deletes it as soon as you add the `svn:ignore` property on its parent directory?

If you need that folder permanently in your repository, but it must remain empty, you can add `junk_folder` to the repository, and then create a `svn:ignore` property that's set to `*`. That will ignore anything in the folder.

My suggestion is to make sure that whatever scripts need `junk_folder` create it if it doesn't exist, and not to add it to your repository. You can use [this pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) to keep it out of your repository. That would be the best way to handle this. There's no reason why an empty directory named `junk_folder` should be in your repository.

Comment: Hi! As above, in edit to question and all comments. Subversion (TortoiseSVN) DOES delete a folder, if you ignore it and if it is already versioned. Ignore without deletion occurs only, if you ignore not versioned folder. For all versioned folders you must use "svn:ignore *" on contents. Because, if you ignore a folder, it will be deleted from repository (but not LWC) upon next commit.

Comment: @trejder You are saying that if there's a versioned folder called `junk_folder`, and I add a property `svn:ignore junk_folder` to the parent folder, Tortoise will delete `junk_folder` without me doing anything? I guess I can see the logic in that, but it sounds dangerous.

Comment: @trejder Just checked the documentation for TortoiseSVN. You can't add a already existing file or folder to the ignore list. However, you can select "Ignore and Unversion files" to the ignore list.

Comment: No. If you use option "Ignore and Unversion files" (from context menu) THEN TortoiseSVN adds a property svn:ignore junk_folder to the parent folder and marks a junk_folder folder as deleted. Upon next commit folder will be deleted from repository (but not from LWC). If you only add a property svn:ignore junk_folder to parent folder manually, then of course TortoiseSVN won't delete anything. But will still report unversioned files in junk_folder. The ultimate solution is to add svn:ignore * to folder, you actually want to ignore (junk_folder in  this example).